# How to correctly setup distributed transactions in JBoss AS 7.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jta

My scenary: a Java EE application that calls a method from an EJB, both hosted in a JBoss AS 7.1.1 server. During insert and update operations in a CRUD page, the JSF application has to save its own data using its own DataSource and additionally to save some other data in other application by calling EJB methods, that will use other DataSource. Both DataSources as configured to **use JTA** (JTA checkbox marked in JBoss DataSource parameters);

Only during **update operations**, the attempt to save data throws an exception. The last parts of the exception stack are as follows:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14729cfa[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@6a370d1a connection handles=0 lastUse=1467805740289 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7a5d9cca pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@31c571ea[pool=CartaoDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@11061a5f[connectionListener=14729cfa connectionManager=4b45c7aa warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:147)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
... 175 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14729cfa[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@6a370d1a connection handles=0 lastUse=1467805740289 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7a5d9cca pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@31c571ea[pool=CartaoDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@11061a5f[connectionListener=14729cfa connectionManager=4b45c7aa warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:604)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
... 178 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:474)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
... 180 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: IJ000356: Failed to enlist: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a0a0546:2fd05d09:577134fa:61c7a status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:552)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:282)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
... 181 more
```

When I disable JTA in the EJB DataSource, the problem disappears.

What is wrong with my environment?

Thanks in advance!

## Update 1

I was requested to give some more information, so there it goes.

This is the use case that makes the problem to happen:

1. User clicks in a link on screen to lead him/her to an edit page
2. In the edit page, user changes values and clicks the save button
3. The save button calls the `update()` method in the managed bean that serves the page
4. The update method begins a transaction and runs two other methods: one acts over the DS declared for the web application (to save local data), other is an EJB method that exposes some functionality from **another** application (to save data in the context of the other application)

Both DSs are path the same data server and both applications are hosted in the same JBoss instance.

The first method works fine, the second produces the error. Since an exception is thrown, the entire transaction is rolled back and nothing really happens in the database.

In my understanding, this is a simple case of application integration, where one applications integrates to another one by using a Java EE standard technology, which is, an EJB call.

I hope this helps to get my case.

Comment: From where are you getting the transaction in step 4?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get exactly how the sequence look like.
I guess that your JSF app use an EJB which use another DS, right?
So it is the same application and server.

If you have more than one DS you need to have a xa-datasource, did you have it?
Please share your DS configuration and more information about your config/app and the warnings in your logile (best is the complete call-sequence) if you have further questions.